# PHP detect non string duplicates and add it to array with their occurence order

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have this dump of an array generated by PHP mysql_fetch_object:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510728 [lon] => 26.276657 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510954 [lon] => 26.277879 ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510954 [lon] => 26.277879 ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.511655 [lon] => 26.278041 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 ) 
)
```

I'm trying to detect duplicates and add it to the same array as new key->values with their occurence order in the array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510728 [lon] => 26.276657 ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510954 [lon] => 26.277879 [order] => [0] ) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510954 [lon] => 26.277879 [order] => [1] ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.511655 [lon] => 26.278041 ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 [order] => [0] ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 [order] => [1] ) 
[6] => stdClass Object ( [lat] => 44.510946 [lon] => 26.275215 [order] => [2] ) 
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think youre looking for "array_count_values()"

Comment: Nope...Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Comment: Well, so cast all the float numbers in strings before you try to count them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly came across this question googling for something else entirely - please forgive the late reply but the question was unanswered and I figured I had a useful answer based on [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

An interesting thing about `array_keys()` is that it takes an optional second value as a **search** value, which retrieves the keys/indices of all matching elements in the array.

Assuming an array `$objects` that replicates your dataset:

```
$objects = [
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510728, 'lon' => 26.276657 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510954, 'lon' => 26.277879 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510954, 'lon' => 26.277879 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.511655, 'lon' => 26.278041 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ],
    (object) ['lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ],
];
```

If we iterate over this array of objects, we can can retrieve the indices of the current **search** object and any **equal** objects in the array; i.e: other instances of the same class with matching attributes and values.

Something like this:

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {

    if (property_exists($object, 'order')) continue;

    $matches = array_keys($objects, $object);

    if (count($matches) > 1) {
        foreach ($matches as $order => $match) {
            $objects[$match]->order = $order;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($objects);
```

A quick summary of the above code:

- Iterate over the `$objects` list.
- If `$object` contains an `order` property already it's been processed - skip.
- Otherwise, get the indices for all matching objects in the array.
- For greater than one (the current object) match, loop over matched indices.
- Apply 'order' property to all matched objects.

This is not thoroughly tested, but it appears to work well and should work for non-contiguous matches as well. Hope this helps!

Result:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510728
      public 'lon' => float 26.276657
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510954
      public 'lon' => float 26.277879
      public 'order' => int 0
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510954
      public 'lon' => float 26.277879
      public 'order' => int 1
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'lat' => float 44.511655
      public 'lon' => float 26.278041
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510946
      public 'lon' => float 26.275215
      public 'order' => int 0
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510946
      public 'lon' => float 26.275215
      public 'order' => int 1
  6 => &
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'lat' => float 44.510946
      public 'lon' => float 26.275215
      public 'order' => int 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there seems to be something wrong though..I don't have the order or the duplicates detected in the original array..that's the result I'm looking to find

Comment: Hi there. No problem. Interesting, I'm not really sure what difference there might be - I'm not sure if you copy/pasted the code in my answer or wrote it out manually but perhaps there's a discrepancy? My first thought is that the objects are not being passed by reference... Note the `&` in the line: `foreach ($objects as &$object) {`. This is important if you want to directly modify the object within the loop without using an index to dereference. If this is not the issue, can you post the code you tried and we can have a look?

Comment: no, of course I didn't just copy/pasted it..but the original array has no order key..I still need to detect those duplicates

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the update. When you say 'original array' you know that where my example uses `$objects`, this is supposed to be your original array, it's not a copy or duplicate of your values. What is the name of your array that you are returning from `mysql_fetch_object`?

Comment: $objects = array (
 array('lat' => 44.510728, 'lon' => 26.276657 ),
 array('lat' => 44.510954, 'lon' => 26.277879 ),
 array('lat' => 44.510954, 'lon' => 26.277879 ),
 array('lat' => 44.511655, 'lon' => 26.278041 ),
 array('lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ),
 array('lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ),
 array('lat' => 44.510946, 'lon' => 26.275215 ),
);

Comment: foreach ($objects as &$object) {
 if (property_exists($object, 'order')) continue;
    $matches = array_keys($objects, $object);

    if (count($matches) > 1) {
        foreach ($matches as $order => $match) {
            $objects[$match]->order = $order;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($objects);

Comment: Okay, so I am a little confused here - are you saying the result in the answer is incorrect, and if so how? If it is not incorrect, am I correct in saying the result you are getting is different; i.e: does not contain the `order` property. 

Can you post the line in your code that calls `mysql_fetch_array` and assigns the result?

Comment: Another thing - I actually just realised that I'm not using the `$object` by reference... so the `&` is not actually necessary :) It was originally because but I modified the code a bit when working on the answer. It's only a small detail but I'm going to edit that out.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it works!! Thanks a lot! I'm goona mark it as answered.

Comment: ah great. no problem! :)